# Creating intellgent dropdown levels in mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build an off-canvas menu that has multiple levels. I've made a quick [codepen](http://codepen.io/robbo/pen/gpNZdp) of my early attempts.

How can I change the code below to have the menu close any open sections if another 'level 1' (+)link is opened? Currently I just have a toggle on any item that is clicked. I'd like to make it a bit more intelligent. Also if the level above is closed all levels below it will close too.

```
$('.off-canvas__content').on('click', '.nav-click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $this = $(this);
    $this.children('i').toggleClass('icon-minus').toggleClass('icon-plus');
    $item = $this.parent('.nav__item');
    $item.toggleClass('nav__item--open');

});
```

Comment: So, for example "Woman" will close, if user clicked on "Man"?

Comment: Yes that is basically it. Although it would be nice to have any child sections also close too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to your code will make things work, I guess:

```
  if($item.hasClass('nav__item--open')) {
          $item.siblings().find('.nav__item--open').removeClass('nav__item--open');
          $item.siblings().find('.icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-minus');
          $item.siblings().removeClass('nav__item--open');



     }
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbXeXg)

Comment: So close, if I close a section then re-open it the child section (if opened previously) is still open, can you think of a way to close all child sections too?

Comment: So you want all child sections closed as well? I'll look into it.

Comment: Done. This one should work as you requested. I updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

hide all parent elements exept element on which is clicked

Edit this:

```
$item.toggleClass('nav__item--open').siblings().toggle();
```